# How to use reverse with optional parameters in django?

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I have the below URL in which I pass an integer value (pk) now when I am calling reverse on this URL I am getting the below-mentioned error.

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [ 
path('batch-postpone/<int:pk>/', postpone_batch, name='batch-postpone'),
]
```

tests.py

```
class ABCTestCases(APITestCase, TestCase):
      self.postpone_batch_url = reverse('batch-postpone')
```

Error that I am getting...

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'batch-postpone' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['batch\\-postpone/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Comment: @Aurélien not really, I wanted to pass this id when I write my test case and not hard code that value in the reverse()

Comment: My bad, duplicate deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Pass in the id in `reverse()` like `reverse('batch-postpone', args=[1])`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

```py
class ABCTestCases(APITestCase, TestCase):
      id = 1
      self.postpone_batch_url = reverse('batch-postpone', args=[id])
```

Comment: I wanted to pass this value "1" dynamically when I write my test case and not hard code that value in the reverse()

Answer (score 0):

The third paragraph of the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) for this function.

```py
from django.urls import reverse

def myview(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('arch-summary', args=[1945]))
```